# VS2010 & LNK2001 error for Q_OBJECT macro

Tags: c++, qt

[[image: Part of mainwindow.h file]]

I'm using VS2013 Express and Qt5.4.1 version.

The errors i´m getting are :

> Error 14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MainWindow::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MainWindow@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ) C:\Users\Raf\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Diploma\Diploma\mainwindow.obj   Diploma
>
> Error 15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MainWindow@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)  C:\Users\Raf\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Diploma\Diploma\mainwindow.obj   Diploma
>
> Error 16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MainWindow@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) C:\Users\Raf\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Diploma\Diploma\mainwindow.obj   Diploma
>
> Error 17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const MainWindow::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@MainWindow@@2UQMetaObject@@B)   C:\Users\Raf\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Diploma\Diploma\mainwindow.obj   Diploma

I looked some similar topics but non of them helped me solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think the Express version of VS can install the Qt plugin and you need that if you don't want to manually configure the moc preprocessor to run on all the files that have a QObject. I'd advise you to get the VS community edition and the Qt plugin for it

Comment: Please paste actual code in the question and not a screenshot of your code editor

Comment: @PeterT i get the same errors in VS2010 so...

Comment: @Kristjan well do you have the Qt plugin installed there and did you makes sure with diagnostic MSBUILD output that it actually runs the "moc" compiler?

Comment: @Kristjan or did you generate the *.sln with qmake?

Comment: @Kristjan Run `QMake`.

Comment: @PeterT nope, i didn´t used command prompt for build

Comment: @Kristjan well you need to run the moc, so either 1.you get the Qt addin for visual studio, 2.you generate your *.sln with qmake 3.you manually run moc on your source file and add the generated *.obj files manually to the linker list

Comment: If your class definition is in a .cpp file then you need to manually include the moc file. Otherwise you won't get the moc functions. As Marco said, you need to paste your code.

Comment: @PeterT so i download Qt Visual Studio addin, run it and it should fix the problem ? I´m new to using  Qt libs so what is a cause for this errors.

Comment: @Kristjan the cause is that there is a metacompiler that generates some helper code for classes that derive from QObject. You need to run the metacompiler on the files defining such classes and link in the output file of the metacompiler with the rest of your project.

Comment: @Kristjan the addin won't magically fix your issue for the existing project but you can then make a new "Qt project" type which will automatically run the metacompiler when you do a build.

Comment: @PeterT so i need to re-do my project

Comment: @Kristjan well if you have a bunch of pre-existing files and settings you can also just build your existing non-Qt project as a static library and add a reference to it in the new Qt project.

Comment: @StuartFisher i added cpp code

Comment: Sorry, I meant class declaration. Where is that? If it is in the .cpp file and not in a .h then you need to add the following line after it: #include "MainWindow.moc". Then run qmake and rebuild.

Comment: @StuartFisher all class declarations are in .h file but i have no .moc files in   file where project is

Comment: You only need to add the .moc include if the declaration is in the .cpp. If the declaration is in the .h and the header file is specified in the .pro file then that should be enough. It sounds like moc just isn't getting run at all, which is what Peter was trying to tell you.

Comment: @StuartFisher i cant add include for moc cuz i have no moc files and it¨s instant error

Comment: qmake generates the moc files. Then the moc compiler uses them to generate the code for the functions you are missing. Is your mainwindow.h file included in the qt makefile (.pro)? i.e. have you got a line that says HEADERS += mainwindow.h ?

Comment: @StuartFisher yes, all the necessary .h files are in .pro

Comment: Don't edit the title with `Solved` or `answered` or whatever... Instead, post an answer or encourage the person who helped you to post an answer and accept it

Comment: Please don't mark the question as `[SOLVED]` in the title. Instead, dig through the comments, take all bits that helped you and form them into an "answer". You will be able then to "Accept" that answer and the whole question will be visible to others as solved, and others will see a nice answer, more readable than a log of comments.

Comment: Of course, it would be the best if the person who actually helped you could do that, since she/he will then get the 'reputation' bonus for helping you. But if they are not interested in doing that, you may do it yourself. You can accept your own answers, too.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl i googled it after a while so i just post a link in new answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After i looked at all the answers that were given i decided that i´ll try to solve the problem by manually moc the .h files which containes Q_OBJECT macro. I randomly googled the most efficient steps (at least for me) .

1. My project was original made in VS2013 but i changed it to VS2010.
2. I followed the steps from this link : http://real3d.pk/forum/index.php?topic=527.0

Comment: I looked at that article you linke to, and that information looks very valuable. Could you add it to your answer in addition to that link? But, don't feel forced/pressed to do it! If you don't like/want/have time, just leave t as it is. Someone else may correct it later, users can improve other users' answer, even I could do that now but I'm pretty busy today. The point is that various sites, including forums, articles or even official documentation, sometimes .. simply evaporate. It's not rare to find on StackOverflow an link-only answer that points to vacuum.